# What is wrong in below .Zip method

Tags: c#

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to convert this part. I get error as cannot be inferred from the usage.

```cs
if( columnsList != null && columnsList.Count != 0 )
{
    List<string> columnList;
    IEnumerable<object> fieldvalues = await generateColumns( props );

    for( int i = 0; i < fieldvalues.Count(); i++ )
    {
        var colValue = fieldvalues.ElementAt( i );
        props.Add(
            columnsList[i].ToString(),
            EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject( colValue )
        );    
    }
```

to

```cs
List<string> columnList;
IEnumerable<object> fieldvalues = await generateColumns( props );

props.Add(
    columnsList.Zip(
        EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject( fieldvalues ),
        ( k, v ) => new { k, v }
    )
    .ToDictionary( x => x.k, x => x.v );
```

Comment: I am using var fieldvalues = ... & generateColumns() return type is Task<IEnumerable<object>>

Comment: can I do a conversion to List and then use .Zip??

Comment: I wrote that in order to let audience understand the type of fieldValues, as it was not clear what type is returned in generateColumns()

Comment: I´d strongy recommend materializing your collection toa `List<T>`. Otherwiese you´re querying the underlying datastore for every iteration, as you´re executing `ElementAt` multiple times. Apart from that: what is `props`?

Comment: You know that `ÌEnumerable<object>` isn't a type, but `IEnumerable<object>` is?

Comment: props is a Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>

Comment: @HimBromBeere Please post it as an answer.

Comment: That´s just a comment, as it doesn´t answer your **actual** question. However it will affect your performance.

Comment: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add` expects a `TKey` and a `TValue`. What you provide is a `TKey,` and a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Don´t overcomplicate things by using febcy linq-statements no-one will ever understand. Your current code gets its job done and is easy to understand.

Comment: ok, can you elaborate more on making collection as List<T> . you meant to change the return type of generateColumns or convert it to .ToList<T> or to an array before running the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off I´d strongly recomment not to call `ElementAt` on every iteration, as doing so will execute the underlying query again and again, leading to a huge performance-issue. You should materialize your list before the loop:

```
if( columnsList != null && columnsList.Count != 0 )
{
    List<string> columnList;
    var fieldvalues = (await generateColumns( props )).ToList();

    for(int i = 0; i < fieldValues.Count; i++)
    {
        props.Add(
            columnList[i].ToString(),
            EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(fieldValue[i]))
        );    
    }
}
```

When you do so, your code gets pretty straightforward and what is even more important: it gets its job done. Why overcomplicating things with some fency LINQ-stuff that you don´t understand? You gain absolutely nothing here, in fact you´re just confusing yourself.

Anyway your problem is that `props` is a dictionary, whose `Add`-method expects a single KVP, not an entire dictionary. Your `Zip`-call already returns a list of KVPs. So all you have to do is calling `ToDictionary` and you´re done:

```
props = columnsList.Zip(
    EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject(fieldvalues),
    (k, v) => new { k, v }
).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v);
```

Comment: I still don't think that's the proper translation... fieldValues and columnsList appear to be two separate collections. But as OP's code is incomplete in that respect I don't think there's much we can do. The example you provide is hopefully enough to point them in the correct direction. They can always ToList as you suggest and continue to use a for loop to access both collections with an index